# How to access phone contacts from an iPhone app and send sms on selecting single or multiple contacts

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, addressbook, addressbookui

I have an iPhone App in which i want so access the phonebook contacts and on the selection of single or multiple contacts i want to send sms to the selected contacts. Please can anybody give me a sample code for doing this app. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We're hear to help those who help themselves, and you won't get a good response here without first demonstrating what you have tried to solve your own problem before asking for the work to be done for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

for (int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++) {
    // Get the next address book record.
    ABRecordRef record = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);        

    // Get array of email addresses from address book record.
    ABMultiValueRef emailMultiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonEmailProperty);
    NSArray *emailArray = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(emailMultiValue);

    [self.contacts addObject:emailArray];
}
```

Hope this get u started...